# Grabbing instagram feed using Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm trying to get all Instagram posts by a specific user in Python. Below my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_images(user):
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + str(user)
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for image in soup.findAll('img'):
        href = image.get('src')
        print(href)

get_images('instagramuser')
```

However, I'm getting the error:

```
UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 14 of the file C:/Users/Bedri/PycharmProjects/untitled1/main.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this: BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser") markup_type=markup_type))
```

So my question, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass parser to `BeautifulSoup`, it's not an error, just a warning.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,'lxml')
```

I would recommend using  > **lxml**  < instead of > **html.parser** <

Instead of requests.get use **urlopen**

here's the code all in **one line**

from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
def get_images(user):

    soup = BeautifulSoup(request.urlopen("https://www.instagram.com/"+str(user)),'lxml')
    for image in soup.findAll('img'):
        href = image.get('src')
        print(href)
get_images('user')
```